# show a group of specific lines from all files with .txt extension

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can I print specific lines (say the 7th to 15th) of each file in the current directory whose name ends in `.txt`?

I Know About 7 and 15 it is done like

```
awk 'FNR==7 || FNR==15' *.txt
```

but if i want to take 7 to 15 then how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` to print 7th to 15th lines of all `.txt` files in the current directory:

```
for i in *.txt; do sed -n '7,15 p' "$i"; done
```

Here `7,15` indicates the line range to print by `sed`, in this case from 7 to 15.

---

As you were using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR>=7 && FNR<=15' *.txt
```

---

Combination of `head` and `tail`:

```
for i in *.txt; do tail -n +7 "$i" | head -9; done
```

---

Or as [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788249/show-a-group-of-specific-lines-from-all-files-with-txt-extension/788255?noredirect=1#comment1183939_788255) mentioned, with the newer GNU `sed` (any supported releases of Ubuntu has it), you can just do:

```
sed -sn '7,15 p' *.txt
```

Here `-s` is to treat each file separately, rather than all of them combined as a single stream.

Comment: Modern versions of GNU sed have a `-s` (`--separate`) flag that causes multiple files on the command line to be treated separately - with that, you can just do `sed -sn '7,15p' file*.txt` instead of using a shell loop

Comment: @steeldriver Brilliant, was looking for that. Thanks.